# django - authentication: user turns into "admin" user when going through follow-up views

Tags: django, authentication

so essentially my problem is this, after I authenticate the user with the dajngo built in system, the user switches to the user "admin" instead of keeping the previous user in session. code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
def new_login_view(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
        data = dict(request.POST)
        data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

        id_client = data['lg_username'][0]
        pass_client = data['lg_password'][0]

        user = authenticate(username=id_client, password=pass_client)

        if user is not None:
            # A backend authenticated the credentials
            ...
            return render(request, 'initial_page.html', dictionary_with_info)
```

when I am in the `initial_page.html` and activate a view, that is:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
```

when I call for `request.user` I get: `User: admin` instead of the user before.

any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only authenticating the user. You have not called `login()` to actually log the user in.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def new_login_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        user = authenticate(username=id_client, password=pass_client)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
```

See the docs on [how to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for more info.

Note that Django comes with built in [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). I recommend that you use the provided login view rather than writing your own.